# How can I fontify a symbol by regexp match group (as in a naming convention)?

Tags: auctex, faces, regular-expressions, font-lock

I want to add better support for `expl3` to AUCTeX.  I have regular expressions that properly group according to the naming conventions for:

- [functions `(\\(?:__)?[a-z]+_)([a-z_]+)(:[nNpTFwcVvxof]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/sL8tY9/1),
- [variables `(\\[cgl]__?)([a-z][a-z_]+)(_[A-Za-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/jW6hN7/2), and
- [key-value segments `\s*([a-z\-]+)\s+(\.[a-z_]+):([nNpTFwcVvxof]*)\s+=`](https://regex101.com/r/aO0tC8/1)

How can I apply faces to both

- the match as a whole and
- the individual groups (overriding the whole match where appropriate)?

Just a proof-of-concept using the function-regexp would be *very* helpful :)

#### `rx` Forms

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-expl3-function-regexp
      (rx symbol-start
          (group "\\" (optional "__") (+ alpha) "_")
          (group (+ (any alpha "_")))
          (group ":" (* (any "nNpTFwcVvxofD")))
          symbol-end)

      LaTeX-expl3-variable-regexp
      (rx symbol-start
          (group "\\" (any "cgl") "_" (optional "_"))
          (group (or (seq (any alpha) "_") "@@_")) 
          (group (any alpha) (+ (any alpha "_")))
          (group "_" (+ alpha))
          symbol-end)

      LaTeX-expl3-keyval-regexp
      (rx (* whitespace)
          (group (any alpha "-"))
          (+ whitespace)
          (group "." (+ (any alpha)))
          (group ":" (* (any "nNpTFwcVvxofD")))
          (+ whitespace) "="))
```

Comment: Are you doing font-locking, i.e., setting `font-lock-keywords`? If so, just use an `OVERRIDE` value of `t` for  the group pattern, and place it after the whole-match pattern. See `C-h v font-lock-keywords`.

Comment: @Drew I had vague thoughts along that line as well, but I'm pitifully under-educated when it comes to `font-lock-mode`. Specifically, I'm not sure how to go about using a single matching regexp and supplying multiple group/face/override values.

Comment: `(info "(elisp) Search-based Fontification")` ?

Comment: Try first using two separate `font-lock-keywords` entries. You can worry about combining them later. The point is to make the second one override anything done by the first one.

Comment: The `font-lock-add-keywords` docstring explains how to fontify different groups ofthe same regexp.

Comment: @SeanAllred See the docstring of the `font-lock-keywords` variable. Use the `(MATCHER HIGHLIGHT ...)` format, where `HIGHLIGHT` stands for `(SUBEXP FACENAME [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])`.

Comment: I think you must drop `symbol-start` when the rest of the regexp start with `\\`.

Comment: @Lindydancer I did end up dropping `symbol-start`, but `\` is classified as a symbol character in TeX modes. Shouldn't this work under those circumstances?

Comment: @SeanAllred, I just tried this in standard latex modein Emacs 24.4.91, there backslash has the syntax class charquote, so is doesn't work. If it has the character class symbol, I guess it would should work.

Comment: @Lindydancer That's odd -- I assumed it was a symbol-char because it behaves with `forward-sexp` -- but I can see why they would have to make an either/or decision (escaping braces, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `font-lock-add-keywords` in a major mode hook to add new rules. The format of the rules is described in the help text to the variable `font-lock-keywords`. In short, your code would look something like:

```
(defun my-LaTeX-expl3-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          `((,LaTeX-expl3-function-regexp
                             (0 face-for-whole-match prepend)
                             (1 face-for-group-one prepend)
                             (2 face-for-group-two prepend))
                            (,LaTeX-expl3-variable-regexp
                             (0 font-lock-variable-name-face prepend))
                            (,LaTeX-expl3-keyval-regexp
                             (0 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
                          t)) ;; Append
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-expl3-hook)
```

Here, I've used `0` to highlight the entire match. If you would like to highlight only parts, supply a integer 1, 2, 3 etc. that corresponds the the parenthesis you would like to highlight. You can supply more than one such rule to each regexp.

The `prepend` flag indicates that this takes precedence over already present fontification. (However, unlike passing `t`, it leaves, for example, the background intact even if it overrides the foreground.)

Finally, if you find that you keywords doesn't work as intended, I would recommend using [font-lock-studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio), an interactive debugger that lets you step the font-lock machinery one step at a time, it highlights matches in the source buffer and in the regexps using a palette of background colors etc.